# curl post image to sinatra api fail

Tags: curl, sinatra

I know this is a question was asked and answered on stackoverflow, but i tried many doesn't help, not sure how to debug it.

my command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H “Content-Type: multipart/form-data” -F "file=/Users/william/Desktop/test.png" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/books
```

terminal output:

```
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: multipart
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 170873
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.5/2014-11-13)
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 11:19:40 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
  <title>NameError at &#x2F;api&#x2F;v1&#x2F;books</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
```

Not sure how to solve this? And i used browser to tested work well:

```
<form action='/api/v1/books' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST'>
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Any help? thanks!

**EDIT** add `@` in front of the path make uploading image works, but still get the output error.
This is a line: `<title>NameError at &#x2F;api&#x2F;v1&#x2F;books</title>` what possible error should it be?

Comment: When specifying the `-F` option `curl` will set the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` header, so you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you! I just checked -F is as form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"curl: (6) Could not resolve host: multipart" means that curl considers "multipart" to be a URL. I suspect it does this because you're not using "real" double quotes (ascii code 34) in that command line but some special unicode ones.

The double quote before file= looks different - and correct.

(and as @mhawke mentioned, setting the Content-Type like that is completely unnecessary as curl does it already by default when -F is used)